# Wrap deferents html tags with a div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following lines in **HTML**:

```
<header class="title">
    <h3>Billing Address</h3>
</header>

<address>
 <p>Address</p>
</address>
```

And I would like to wrap them between a new `div` using jQuery because I don't have access to the HTML.

If I use `.before()` and `.after()`, it doesn't work

```
$('header').before('<div="new-div">');
$('address').after('</div>');
```

I have tried with `.wrap()` and `.append()`, but also doesn't work.

The result shoulbe be:

```
<div class="new-div">
    <header class="title">
        <h3>Billing Address</h3>
    </header>

    <address>
     <p> Address </p>
    </address>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but the address tag should not be used for a random address. As per the specification, it should only be used for the contact details of a specific page, section, or article. Given your heading of Billing Address", this does not match this criteria and therefore a p should be used.

Comment: Thanks Ian Devlin for the comment. As I said, I don't have access to the html :( But I will ask for correction :) Thanks a gain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `.wrapAll()` instead of `.wrap()`:

> wrapAll : Wrap an HTML structure around all elements in the set of matched elements.

```
$( "header,address" ).wrapAll( "<div class='new' />");
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9mhtzb4c/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `prepend()` along with `append()`

```
$('header').prepend('<div="new-div">');
$('address').append('MYDIV</div>');
```

Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/dcmg4cL5/) fiddle

Comment: Hearty Thanks I think wrapAll is better. Thanks anyway :)